# Using two LocalDateTime instances to calculate a duration

Tags: java, date, time, timezone, jodatime

I am trying to calculate the duration between two instances of `LocalDateTime`. The special thing here is that each instance of `LocalDateTime` could be from ANYWHERE in the world:

`LocalDateTime start` could be from *Nevada* and `LocalDateTime end` could be from *Tokyo*. Each "time" associated with the `LocalDateTime` is, obviously enough, local to that location.

So if I said...

`LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse("2015-07-14T10:00:00");` and said that `start` represented Chicago, that would mean 10:00 AM in Chicago time.
Then I could say...

`LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.parse("2015-07-14T03:00:00");` and `end` represents Moscow, so it is 3:00AM in Moscow time.

Can I create a robust enough solution that will allow `start` and `end` to represent *any* cities in the world and still correctly calculate the duration between the two?

Comment: Can't you convert them to a common timezone (such as UTC) ?

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia I think if I convert to a common timezone, I would first have to assign `start` and `end` to their own respective timezone, and then convert that to UTC. This would cause errors if I'm calculating a duration over the border of DST (Daylight Saving Time).

Comment: You need the time zone for both instances. Once you have the time zones, [convert each LocalDateTime to a DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html#toDateTime-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-), and [compute the duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html#Duration-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-org.joda.time.ReadableInstant-).

Comment: Alternatively, convert to Unix timestamp and do the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## "LocalDateTime" Does Not Mean A Particular Locality

I think you misunderstand the purpose of `LocalDateTime`. The "local" means *any* locality, **not a specific locality**. As in "Christmas starts at midnight on December 25, 2015" where we mean *any* locality’s midnight. Christmas starts in Paris several hours earlier than Montréal, for example.

If you know the date-time is meant to represent a date-time in Nevada, the use a Joda-Time `DateTime` assigned the [proper time zone name](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) of `America/Boise`. In the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)) built into Java 8 and later, use a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object with assigned time zone.

Similarly, if you know the date-time is local to Tokyo, do *not* use `LocalDateTime`. Use a Joda-Time `DateTime` with an assigned time zone of `Asia/Tokyo`.

## Elapsed

Elapsed time between a pair of `LocalDateTime` instances makes no sense. For example, the times may be 14:00 and 18:00 on the same date, but that does *not* mean four hours difference. If you really meant 14:00 in Paris and 18:00 in Chicago, that would be several hours difference, not two.

I am not discussing calculating elapsed time as that has been handled many many times on StackOverflow. I'm trying to clarify some concepts here. Then you can move on to the [existing Questions & Answers for calculating elapsed time](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java%20date%20elapsed).

## Databases Store UTC

Generally in SQL databases you should be using the data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (a.k.a. `TIMESTAMPZ` with a `Z` for "[zulu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones)"). This misnomer actually means "with respect for time zone". Incoming data with an offset from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) or other time zone information is adjusted to UTC. The data's offset or time zone is *not* preserved.

The SQL data type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` (a.k.a. `TIMESTAMP`) means the same as a `LocalDateTime` in Java: no time zone at all. Not tied to the timeline. Any offset or time zone information with input data is *ignored*, no adjustment made.

[Postgres doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) may help explain.

## Stick With UTC

When retrieving such a value from the database, the UTC value may be adjusted to a particular time zone by your admin tool (such as pgAdmin in Postgres) or your database driver or by your app.

In your app it is generally best to keep your date-time values in UTC as much as possible. Do nearly all of your storage, business logic, and data exchange in UTC. Only adjust to a particular time zone when expected by the user.

## To Convert A LocalDateTime To A Time Zone

If you do have a `LocalDateTime` object, and you want to assign it a time zone, here is some example code. We also adjust to get the very same moment as seen in Montréal and in UTC. First the example is shown in Joda-Time, then in java.time.

### Joda-Time

Example in Joda-Time 2.8.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = new LocalDateTime( "2015-07-14T10:00:00" );  // Nowhere in particular.
DateTimeZone zoneChicago = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Chicago" );
DateTime dateTimeChicago = ldt.toDateTime( zoneChicago );
DateTime dateTimeMontreal = dateTimeChicago.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeChicago.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "LocalDateTime (nowhere): " + ldt );
System.out.println( "Chicago: " + dateTimeChicago );
System.out.println( "Montréal: " + dateTimeMontreal );
System.out.println( "UTC: " + dateTimeUtc);
```

When run.

```
LocalDateTime (nowhere): 2015-07-14T10:00:00.000
Chicago: 2015-07-14T10:00:00.000-05:00
Montréal: 2015-07-14T11:00:00.000-04:00
UTC: 2015-07-14T15:00:00.000Z
```

### java.time

Example in java.time of Java 8 Update 51.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2015-07-14T10:00:00" );  // Nowhere in particular.
ZoneId zoneChicago = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" );
ZonedDateTime zdtChicago = ZonedDateTime.of( ldt, zoneChicago );
ZonedDateTime zdtMontreal = zdtChicago.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = zdtChicago.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ); // ZoneOffset is a subclass of ZoneId.
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "LocalDateTime (nowhere): " + ldt );
System.out.println( "Chicago: " + zdtChicago );
System.out.println( "Montréal: " + zdtMontreal );
System.out.println( "UTC: " + zdtUtc);
```

When run.

```
LocalDateTime (nowhere): 2015-07-14T10:00
Chicago: 2015-07-14T10:00-05:00[America/Chicago]
Montréal: 2015-07-14T11:00-04:00[America/Montreal]
UTC: 2015-07-14T15:00Z
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. But what if I'm calculating times over and over again, by reading them from a database and each `start` and `end` can be from different cities every time? Is there no robust solution?

Comment: @Joshua See added sections to my Answer. I suggest you search for "Java date" in StackOverflow to do some study and get the hang of handling date-time. It is an interesting but tricky topic.